# Access resources grails 3

Tags: resources, gsp, grails-controller, grails-3.0

Good day. I can't find information about resources in grails 3.

Where I need to put images etc. And how I need to use this images and other resources on GSP page.

Where I can put properties file and how I can read them after?

Thank you.

Comment: Its in the docs. Check it out: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#resources

Comment: How can I get property files from assests folder in my util classes?

Comment: Grails has a different directory structure than regular Java projects. Put static files (images, css, js, etc.) in the /grails-app/assets directory. Grails configuration is done through the /grails-app/conf, build.gradle and the init directory. You will not be using XML or .properties files for configuration. For more details read the docs. Its all in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your image say excel.png under your

```
project/grails_app/assets/images
```

directory. Then access the image in your gsp as under.

```
<asset:image src="excel.png" width="40" height="30" align="left"/></a>
```